# Interchange the integral and summation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading a paper for my work, and it has an identity

> $$\frac{2}{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sin\left[\frac{2\pi n(t-x)}{L}\right]dx = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left[\frac{2\pi n(t-x)}{L}\right]\,dx$$

where $f$ is a periodic function with period $L$ on $[0, L]$.

Is this correct that the summation and the integral can interchange? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Is $i$ an integer or not?

Comment: Sorry, its a typo.

Comment: What is the assumption for $f$?

Comment: $f$ is a periodic function with period $L$ on $[0, L]$

Comment: The integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals and vice versa

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra This is only true when the sum converges uniformly.

Comment: @Alfred It is true if the sum converges uniformly but not only true when the sum converges uniformly.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left[\frac{2\pi n(t-x)}{L}\right]$ fails to exist.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark mentioned in the comments the inner sum after the interchange does not exist (unless $x-t$ is an integer multiple of $L$) so the interchange is surely illegal.

However, I suspect the next step after that was to identify the inner sum with a delta function. Since a delta function is a distribution, not a function, we would be very surprised if the "integral representation" of it was a function.

What's going on here is subtle and often glossed over. The safe way to do the derivation is to use a convergence factor of $e^{-\epsilon n}$ or some other regularization to control the inner sum, then make the (legal) interchange, then perform the sum, then do the integral, taking the limit as the regularization goes away (i.e.$\epsilon\to 0$). The thing you get out of the inner sum is a distribution that converges to the delta function as the regularization goes away.

But the unsafe way is faster and generally works, so people pretty much always compute that way, figuring they're innocent until proven guilty.